# Prestashop Translation

Tags: translation, prestashop, language-translation

I have imported some other languages to my shop. When I change the language, **all the fields are changed** (items, categories, etc...) but products (name, description) and categories are **in English**.

I understand these language will not change but I also **want those languages to be changed**. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change them manually
when you create new language, you'll see its flag next to the input fields, just click it and you can enter the text in that language you select

Comment: after enabling friendly URL you need to go to Tools -> Generators and generate the .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop (1.4) comes in 5 languages, and you can get language packs for many other languages (some more complete than others), that were contributed by members.

However, Prestashop will not automatically translate anything that you manually added to your shop (IE Categories, Products, CMS pages, Modules, etc..), you can either manually enter the translations, or you can use a module to automatically translate those using google translate.

You can see an example of a module that does automatic translation at http://www.presto-changeo.com/en/prestashop-modules/19-website-translator.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you have to translate them manually. The packs are only available for default products.

You also can install a module to translate it automatically (probably utilizing Google Translate). But if you are selling, I don't think you should do that. As the automatic translation sometimes sounds funny. IT HURTS YOUR PROSPECT CUSTOMERS and you are loosing sale.